# Pyqt Combobox like Html

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I'm using PyQt5 and I want to assign a value for each item in QComboBox, like the HTML combobox.

I know I can get the selected item or index, but I want to get the value.

For example in HTML:

```
 <select>
  <option value="0.18">Name 1</option>
  <option value="0.36">Name 2</option>
  <option value="0.40">Name 3</option>
  <option value="0.43">Name 4</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using userData and here is a working example

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        dataToAdd = {"Name 1" : 0.18, "Name 2" : 0.36, "Name 3" : 0.41, "Name 4" : 0.43,}
        self.btn.addItem("Select")
        for eachItem in dataToAdd:
            val = dataToAdd[eachItem]
            self.btn.addItem(eachItem, userData=QtCore.QVariant(str(val)))
        self.btn.move(20, 20)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.btn.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.foo)
        self.show()

    def foo(self, value):
        itemValue = self.btn.itemData(value).toString()
        itemText = self.btn.itemText(value)
        print itemValue, "====", itemText

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please check doc's for more details http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#addItem